# Reference to URL not showing up

Tags: bibtex, urls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL of cited web site in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/url-of-cited-web-site-in-bibliography)

I want this reference to a URL to show up, but it doesn't. This is how I add the entry in the bib file. I've also tried it as webpage and as url, but it doesn't show up in the references. It only shows the author and title. How do I make it show the URL?

```
@misc{vlsibackp_t,
 Author = {Mariusz Bernacki},
 Date-Added = {2010-12-21 15:37:30 -0600},
 Date-Modified = {2010-12-22 12:21:00 -0600},
 Lastchecked = {December 22, 2010},
 Title = {Backpropagation},
 Url = {http://home.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html},
 Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://home.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html}}
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The OP is using the `plain` BibTeX style.

Comment: too less informations. From your context I suppose that you are using biblatex, but that is all ...

Comment: As Herbert says, we need some more information here. What is included in the output from BibTeX depends on BibTeX style you are using.

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from the underscores in that URL. In this [related](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34149/bibtex-references-not-compiling-because-of-lastpage-package) [questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27382/problem-with-escaped-characters-in-bibliography-when-using-mendeley-natbib-ur) the suggested solution is to either load `\usepackage{url}` or to switch to `biblatex`+`biber` instead of `bibtex`.

Answer (score 4):

Again, too little information. However, I have no problem. Running pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@misc{vlsibackp_t,
 Author = {Mariusz Bernacki},
 Date-Added = {2010-12-21 15:37:30 -0600},
 Date-Modified = {2010-12-22 12:21:00 -0600},
 Lastchecked = {December 22, 2010},
 Title = {Backpropagation},
 Url = {http://home.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html},
 Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://home.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}

\begin{document}
foo~\cite{vlsibackp_t}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does putting `\url` before the hyperlink help?  As in

```
\url{http://home.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html}
```

Comment: Well the document is really long so I can't post the whole thing. but the bibliography says:

% section conclusion (end) 
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib/mybib}