# URL of cited web site in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, natbib, urls, chicago-style

I am using `natbib` with the `chicago` style as bibliography style.
I am trying to cite a web site, but in the bibliography the URL (given in the BibTeX entry) is not printed.

Is there a simple solution to this matter?
What am I doing wrong?

ok, as a little example (the entries are generated via Mendeley)

```
@misc{Carlson2011, 
  author = {Carlson, Nicholas},
  booktitle = {Businessinsider.com},
  title = {{How Many Users Does Twitter REALLY  Have?}},
  url = {www.businessinsider.com/chart-of-the-day-how-many-users-does-twitter-really-have-2011-31/3},
  year = {2011}
}
```

and the output in chicago-style looks like this:

> Carlson, N. (2011). How Many Users Does Twitter REALLY Have?

Comment: Welcome to TeX Stack Exchange! In order for the participants of this group to be in a better position to provide advice, it would be helpful if you provided a `minimum working example` (MWE). In the present case, it would be especially helfpul if you provided a specific example of a bib entry that has a URL you're trying to get typeset but (as of now) is not.

Comment: Hi! It's hard to provide a example, since it just doen't include the url field of the respective BibTex entry. Maybe that is a general issue with the bibstyle chicago?

Comment: @Thomas: No there is no general issue.

Comment: Can you place one of the entries in your BibTeX file that you know has a URL? Perhaps there's an issue with the way it is formatted.

Comment: ok, i edited my question.

Comment: Thanks. To make sure that we get comments directed to us, use the @ symbol and start typing a name. A box will pop up to help you fill in the rest. As this is your question, everything automatically comes to you anyway. On another note, that's a hell of a URL...

Comment: The usual advice is to use `howpublished = "\url{http://...}"`. For long URLs. Also make sure that you're using the `hyperref` package or the `url` package so that the URL is allowed to break to a new line.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The style `chicago` provides the following entries:

```
address    author    booktitle      chapter
edition    editor    howpublished   institution
journal    key       month          note
number     organization             pages
publisher  school    series         title
type       volume    year
```

You see there is no entry `url`. To use one you can use the entry `note`:

```
note={\url{www.businessinsider.com/chart-of-the-day-how-many-users-does-twitter-really-have-2011-31/3}}
```

---

**EDIT**

To find which entries will be supported by a bibliography style you can open the relevant bibliography file. The extension of such a file is `bst`. To find the file on your computer use the command `kpsewhich`:

```
marco@marco-linux:~$ kpsewhich chicago.bst
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/chicago/chicago.bst
```

To open the file via the terminal you can use in Ubuntu:

```
gedit `kpsewhich chicago.bst`
```

on a Mac:

```
open `kpsewhich chicago.bst`
```

In the file you find all provided entries in the following structure at the beginning of the file:

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    ...
  }
  {}
```

---

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Carlson2011, 
  author = {Carlson, Nicholas},
  booktitle = {Businessinsider.com},
  title = {{How Many Users Does Twitter REALLY  Have?}},
  note = {\url{www.businessinsider.com/chart-of-the-day-how-many-users-does-twitter-really-have-2011-31/3}},
  year = {2011}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\cite{Carlson2011}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\end{document}
```

The example uses the package `hyperref` to provide the command `\url`. Instead you can use the package `url`.

Answer (score 11):

I checked the file `chicago.bst` on my TeX system (MacTeX 2011): its file date is "28 August 1992" and its abstract notes that it is a "BibTeX bibliography style that follows the 'B' reference style of the 13th Edition of the Chicago Manual of Style". Given that this style file was created in 1992, it's probably not surprising that it does *not* recognize (let alone process) the "URL" field of a bib entry. Hence, even if your `bib` entries have `url` fields, they are not going to be printed out if you use this style file.

A real solution would be to find a (much more!) recent style file that implements the recommendations of the *current*, i.e., *16th* edition of "Chicago". Off the top of my head, I'm not aware of such a file, but hopefully other participants in this group can chime in and provide advice. A temporary workaround (i.e., until you manage to find such a `.bst` file) is to change the field type from "url" to "note" of your bib entries. If you choose to pursue this route, you will also need to encase the URLs in the command `\url{...}` and load the `url` package with the `hyphens` option, i.e., `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}`. Taking your example, you'd rewrite it as:

```
@misc{Carlson2011, 
  author = {Carlson, Nicholas},
  booktitle = {Businessinsider.com},
  title = {{How Many Users Does Twitter REALLY Have?}},
  note = {Available online at \url{www.businessinsider.com/chart-of-the-day-how-many-users-does-twitter-really-have-2011-31/3}},
  year = {2011}
}
```

Alternatively, you could consider switching from `bibtex/natbib` to `biblatex` and loading the package [biblatex-chicago](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/). See the question [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib) for some guidance on how to achieve the (not too onerous) transition from bibtex/natbib to biblatex.

Answer (score 8):

If you are willing to switch to [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) (see [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/10102) for the many advantages of `biblatex`), you could use its very complete implementation of the chicago style, [`biblatex-chicago`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago). It provides an `online` entry type, which is specifically tailored for online publications / websites (url, date accessed, etc.).

For the `@online` entry type see also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3608/120395

Answer (score 7):

I've managed to produce a new chicago.bst file with url included thanks to this [script](http://nxg.me.uk/dist/urlbst/) that adds url support for any bst file.

If you prefer you can download my chicago.bst file [here](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BxuxVy5_wLuSUG1hUU40c1AxTFE)

Comment: Thanks for providing this. Have you considered updating it to support the `urldate` BibTeX field so that it properly appends *(accessed* date *)* per this [Chicago Style Guide](http://www.bibme.org/citation-guide/chicago/website).

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I'm not using this at this moment, but according to the script's page there's a field for last accessed date:  _url and lastchecked, to associate a URL with a reference, along with the date at which the URL was last checked to exist_

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that I did not undestand how to get the 'urldate' and 'url' shown at all.

The solution for me was to use

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The library file (mybib.bib) was created using Mendeley https://www.mendeley.com/newsfeed

I hope this helps newbies like me.