# Displaying URL in bibliography exported from Mendeley

Tags: bibtex, urls

After following instructions from [Mendeley on creating and exporting bib](http://www.mendeley.com/blog/tipstricks/howto-use-mendeley-to-create-citations-using-latex-and-bibtex/) using bibtex, citations containing URL were incomplete in the bibliography output (url absent). For example:

```
@article{Cover1998,
author = {Cover, Robin},
file = {:Users/XXXX/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Cover/Cover Pages/Cover - 1998 - XML and semantic transparency.html:html},
journal = {Cover Pages},
publisher = {OASIS},
title = {{XML and semantic transparency}},
url = {http://xml.coverpages.org/xmlAndSemantics.html http://www.citeulike.org/group/2308/article/1449562},
year = {1998}
}
```

Results in

> Cover, R. (1998). XML and semantic transparency

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. If you want anybody to help you, please help them by providing a minimal example and point out what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL of cited web site in bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/url-of-cited-web-site-in-bibliography)

Comment: @Nigel_V_Thomas This is not a _working_ example. Check out http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/3240. This is what Marc van Dongen wanted to tell you. We need to see, what style you're using. Because very likely it's a style-dependent issue.

Comment: Thanks! The solution suggested there is okay, but requires a markup change in bib, by adding note. Instead, a simpler solution based on final suggestion was to switch to using biblatex. Having done this, I can see URL as follows
> Robin Cover. “XML and semantic transparency”. In: Cover Pages (1998). URL: http:
//xml.coverpages.org/xmlAndSemantics.htmlhttp://www.citeuli
ke.org/group/2308/article/1449562

Comment: @Thorsten I see! Thanks, I will do this next time.

Comment: Without knowing which bibliographystyle (`.bst`) file you use, it's not possible to give further advice. In the BibTeX system, it's the `.bst` file that contains information on how (and even if!) to render various fields of a bibliographic entry -- such as the URL field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mendeley recreates periodically the bib file, and then, modify manually the bib file does not work because it will be re-written. But here's a trick works just fine.
At Mendeley Desktop:

1. Change the document type (from that reference you want to get its
   URL included) from "Journal Article" to "Web Page" in the Details
   tab.
2. Activate the "Medium" field for web pages (Tools > Options > Document Details)
3. go back to the document details tab, and paste the URL (http://www.d...) at the newly visible "Medium" field. ... and
   that's it!! enjoy.

the explanation is that the "Medium" field in Mendeley is exported to the bib file as "howpublished = {http://www.d..."
and then, this field is recognized and included by most bibliography styles. 
(credits http://www.bar54.de/2013/10/mendeley-webpage-entry-urls-in-bibtex-export/ )

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the suggestions!

The solution for me, was to switch to using biblatex.

Having done this, I can see URL as follows

> Robin Cover. “XML and semantic transparency”. In: Cover Pages (1998). URL: http: //xml.coverpages.org/xmlAndSemantics.htmlhttp://www.citeuli ke.org/group/2308/article/1449562

Comment: Mendeley only let's me export as bibtex -- how did you use biblatex?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, make sure to fill the field "Authors" so that the field "Citation Key" is automatically generated. For me, when this was missing I couldn't see the reference in my LateX file.