# Customizing Bibliography alpha

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, ieee-style

I am pretty new to Latex.  I am using the bibliography style - alpha.  I use Citavi to manage my Citations and Citavi exports my bibliography in Bibtex(.bib) IEEE format which contains the last accessed date of an @electronic document as urldate.

```
urldate = {29.02.2012}
```

Now, when a .bbl file is generated from this .bib file, the urldate field is overlooked.  So, I do not have any last accessed date appearing in my bibliography.

Question: How can I make the last accessed date appear in my bibliography?

Comment: The `alpha` bibliography style is one of the original styles created for BibTeX, i.e., it's been around for more than 20 years. As such, it does *not* recognize (read, process) fields such as `url` or `urldate`. You need to use a more modern style file. The IEEE provides the style file `IEEEtran.bst` as well as several other files. One of these files may meet your needs. (Type `texdoc ieeetran` and search for section XIII for more info on this bibliography style.)

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/url-of-cited-web-site-in-bibliography/36255#36255

Comment: @Mico Please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @lockstep -- done! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alpha` bibliography style is one of the original styles created for BibTeX, i.e., it's been around for more than 20 years. As such, it does not recognize (i.e., process) fields such as `url` or `urldate`. You need to use a more modern style file.

The IEEE provides the style file [IEEEtran.bst](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/) as well as several related style files; one of these files may meet your needs. Peruse the user guide, [How to use the IEEEtran BibTeX Style](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf), for more information.

Specifically, this style file provides for an `entry` (something in BibTeX that starts with an `@`) named `electronic`. The user guide has the following to say about this entry type:

> IEEEtran.bst provides the “electronic” entry type for internet
>   references. IEEEtran.bst also provides the aliases
>   “online”, “internet”, “webpage” and “www” for compatibility
>   with some existing BIBTEX database and style files. However,
>   “electronic” (or perhaps “online” for those who also use
>   Philipp Lehman’s biblatex) should be used for all new
>   work. IEEE formats electronic references differently by not
>   using italics or quotes and separating fields with periods rather
>   than commas. Also, the `date` is enclosed within parentheses
>   and is placed closer to the title. This is probably done to
>   emphasize that electronic references may not remain valid on
>   the rapidly changing internet. Note also the liberal use of the
>   howpublished field to describe the form or category of the
>   entries.
>
> The `organization` and `address` fields may also be used.

From this, it would appear that you could rename the `urldate` field name to `date` and be all set.