# Last visited URL in apa style

Tags: bibliographies, urls, apa-style

I'm using the `apa-good.bst` file to typeset my bibliography in APA style. I need to include something like "Last visited..." (using the `urldate` variable) when I cite a webpage but I don't know how I can do this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Your referenced bibliography style isn't available at CTAN. So I **guess** You are using the following file:

[**ucbthesis** -- LaTeX template for typesetting UCB thesis -- apa-good.bst](http://code.google.com/p/ucbthesis/source/browse/trunk/main/apa-good.bst?r=2)

The style support the following entries:

```
address author booktitle chapter edition
editor howpublished institution journal
key month note number organization pages
publisher school series title type url
volume year
```

In relation to my previous answer

[URL of cited web site in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/url-of-cited-web-site-in-bibliography/36255#36255)

You can simple add to the field `note`:

```
note="Last visited..."
```