# Cannot see the .bib file contents

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm realty new at using LaTeX. But I have an problem getting an `.bib` file to show in my output:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Today}
\maketitle


\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{Litteratur}

Content

\end{document}
```

And my `Litteratur.bib` looks like this:

```
@book{goossens93,
author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
year      = "1993",
publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
```

I'm using Latexian as my editor, and I have been into and change the setting so the type set I set to 2. And then exporting BibTeX is checked.
But then I  look at the log file after exporting. It's saying this:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2011)
The top-level auxiliary file: TSWLatexianTemp_000003.aux
The style file: alpha.bst
Database file #1: Litteratur.bib
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Friedl2006"
(There was 1 warning)
```

But I don't no where it gets that `Friedl2006`.

Comment: You mustn't specify the `.bib` extension.

Comment: You have no `\cite` commands in your source. Without them, you will get no citations. This is covered in most LaTeX guides: perhaps take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex

Comment: I have tried to use \Cite. But the it only shows me [?]

Comment: You have to run `latex` `bibtex` `latex` `latex`. pl try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your examples doens't show everything. I am trying to point out some relevant problems:

- You need a specific bib file with the correct syntax. The syntax of a bib file are shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX#Entry_types). An other relevant question is [URL of cited web site in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/url-of-cited-web-site-in-bibliography/36255#36255) The example is:

  ```
  @Book{abramowitz+stegun,
    author    = "Milton {Abramowitz} and Irene A. {Stegun}",
    title     = "Handbook of Mathematical Functions with
                 Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables",
    publisher = "Dover",
    year      =  1964,
    address   = "New York",
    edition   = "ninth Dover printing, tenth GPO printing"
   }
  ```
- To get a reference inside your document you have to call them. For example a specific entry is called via `\cite{abramowitz+stegun}`. If you want to get everything of your bib file in the bibliography without citing you can simple use `\nocite{*}`.
- Last but not least the compiling is important. The correct order of compiling is:

  ```
  (pdf)latex filename.tex
  bibtex filename.aux
  (pdf)latex filename.tex
  (pdf)latex filename.tex
  ```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of using \cite i used \nocite{*} instead and now it works.

Answer (score 3):

Citation from the Latexian FAQ:

"I see question marks where labels and references should appear in Preview and Live Preview. What should I do?

By default, Preview and Live Preview only do a single typesetter run without any options to maximize performance (Export does multiple runs). You can configure Preview and Live Preview to do multiple runs and/or run BibTeX in the Preview section of Latexian's Preferences. Then, your labels and references should appear."

In own words: go to: Latexian --> Preferences --> Preview then under "typesetting options" mark "BibTex" and set "number of typesetting runs" to 2.