# Add Retrieved-on-date field, using natbib and agsm

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

For my bibliography I am using `natbib` package with `agsm` style using following commands

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

Question:
How Can I insert "Retrieved” or “Last accessed with my Reference Entry I get something like this:

> Tams Barta, 2012. Elixir 2, A System Information Monitoring Application and Widget. Android Market. Available at: http://goo.gl/30udM **[Accessed January 4, 2012]**

Comment: The easiest way is to use the field `note`.

Comment: Do you mean                                                     '@misc{Tams_Barta_2012,
title = {Elixir 2},
author = {Barta, Tams},
url= {http://goo.gl/30udM},
year = {2012},
 note = {[Accessed May 31st, 2012]}
}'

Comment: Indeed, that would be a way to go.

Comment: Using **note** tag works for me. But I don't know how to mark your comment as answer. Mods, please mark Marco's comment as accepted answer.

Comment: @KhurramMajeed: I added a small answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question can be answered with the following question:

[URL of cited web site in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/url-of-cited-web-site-in-bibliography/36255#36255)

Based on this information use:

```
note = "[Accessed May 31st, 2012]"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `note` solution also works with the `harvard` package (in case anyone was wondering). I did get some ugly line breaks though so I enclosed it in an `mbox` like this:

```
note = {\mbox{[Last Accessed: February 20th 2017]}}
```

This usually puts the entire `note` field on its own line (unless the `title` field is very short), which can be a desired look. Another solution suggested by @Mico is:

```
 note = {[Last~Accessed: February~20th~2017]}}
```

This will allow a line break only right in front of the date.

Comment: improve it, so it counts as a valuable answer.

Comment: +1. Is it necessary (or desirable), though, to prevent line breaks after "Accessed:" or "20th"? Writing `note = {[Last~Accessed: February~20th 2017]}` may be a good compromise.

Comment: I tried that and it still looked a bit awkward to me, but that's a matter of taste depending on what you're going for. I added it!