# Adding "Accessed" and "Available from" for agsm bibliography style (Harvard Format)

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, harvard-style

I'm writing a final year dissertation, and our university (University of Westminster, UK) requires us to use Harvard referencing format. I have followed [this](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/administration-and-support-services/library/public/LaTeX-example-Harvard-apr-2019.pdf) tutorial to include Harvard formatting into my Overleaf document.

As per the [guidelines (5.4.1 in the document)](https://www.westminster.ac.uk/sites/default/public-files/general-documents/Referencing%20Your%20Work%20booklet_06.1.pdf) provided by the university, when accessing online journals/research papers, it is required to have the `Available from...` and `Accessed...` information (See the image below).

[image]

I've tried doing what's stated in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58039/add-retrieved-on-date-field-using-natbib-and-agsm) thread for the following entry, and have gotten the output below.

**Input:**

```latex
@article{banbury2021micronets,
    title        = {Micronets: Neural network architectures for deploying tinyml applications on commodity microcontrollers},
    author       = {Banbury, Colby and Zhou, Chuteng and Fedorov, Igor and Matas, Ramon and Thakker, Urmish and Gope, Dibakar and Janapa Reddi, Vijay and Mattina, Matthew and Whatmough, Paul},
    year         = 2021,
    journal      = {Proceedings of Machine Learning and Systems},
    volume       = 3,
    url          = {https://proceedings.mlsys.org/paper/2021/file/a3c65c2974270fd093ee8a9bf8ae7d0b-Paper.pdf},
    note = "[Accessed 29th September, 2021]"
}
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

I would like to have it display as shown in the University Referencing guidelines in the link mentioned and shown above. How may I achieve it?

Comment: "Harvard style" is just a synonym for "authoryear-style citation call-outs". There's a LaTeX package called `harvard`, which provides several bibliography styles, including the `agsm` style. However, there are plenty of other bibliography styles which, when used with suitable citation management package such as `natbib`, are also capable of producing authoryear-style citation call-outs. Is there a particular reason for why you chose to work with the `agsm` bib style?

Comment: To be honest, I'm a beginner at LaTex. I started using Overleaf at most 3 months ago and back then the first link that explains how to add Harvard referencing was [this link](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/administration-and-support-services/library/public/LaTeX-example-Harvard-apr-2019.pdf)

Comment: `agsm` is a BibTeX style, which is incompatible with `biblatex`, so I removed the `biblatex` tag to avoid confusion (especially since `agsm` is only mentioned in the title and the question body does not state explicitly how you generate your bibliography).