# How do I add the URL to a phjcp/similar bibliography style?

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, urls

I like the phjcp style. [Authors][Journal][Volume in bold][First Page][(Year)]. I would also like to include the URL of the paper by the end. I haven't figured out how to do this.
I have loaded the hyperref package, cite package and the url packages. My bib file was created with Mendeley 
1.9.2 (Mac) and I am using Texmaker 4.0.2 (Mac) and Working with MacOSX 10.7.5.

A typical reference on my bibfile looks like this, although not all of my entries have a

```
@article{Narayanan2010,
author = {Narayanan, H and Verner, S N and Mills, K L and Remkemer, R and Garikipati, K},
doi = {10.1088/0953-8984/22/19/194122},
file = {:Users/Lorean/Dropbox/Journal Articles/J. Phys. Condens. Matter/Narayanan et al.. 2010.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0953-8984},
journal = {J. Phys.: Condens. Matter},
month = may,
number = {19},
pages = {194122},
title = {{In silico estimates of the free energy rates in growing tumor spheroids}},
url = {http://stacks.iop.org/0953-8984/22/i=19/a=194122?key=crossref.6feb263aa96b7af8953f1a389eebd6fe},
volume = {22},
year = {2010}
}
```

My bibliography looks like this:

```
\bibliographystyle{phjcp}
\bibliography{library}
```

> [74] A. Noy, D. V. Vezenov, and C. M. Lieber, Annu. Rev. Mater. Sci.
>   27, 381 (1997).

Does anyone know how to add the URL in the end of the reference, so that I can use that as a hyperlink to open the article?. If it is not possible with this bibliography style, would there be a similar one?

Answer (score 3):

The `phcjp` bibliography style doesn't feature a field call `url`. (This omission probably isn't surprising given that the style file was last updated in 1988...) Fortunately, the entry type `@article` does feature an "optional" field called `note`. (This is true of most other entry types as well.) If the `note` field is provided, its contents will be shown at the end of the bibliographic entry.

You could thus proceed as follows:

- Be sure to load either the `url` or the `hyperref` package to activate the command `\url`.
- Enter something like the following in the entry's `note` field:

  ```
  note = "Available online at \url{some.long.url.string.here}, last accessed on <some date>"
  ```
- If a field called `url` already exists in your bibliographic entry (say, because it was generated by Mendeley), just change the field name from `url` to `note` and encase the URL string in an `\url{...}` macro. If you want to provide further information (such as when the electronic entry was last accessed), you can do that too.

Answer (score 0):

A complete answer (wasn't going to fit on the comments):

The thing is that `phcjp` style (`\bibliographystyle{phjcp}`) does not natively use URLs. This means that if you use them, your work will no longer be "phcjp compliant".

Nevertheless, there is nothing keeping you from using URLs if you want to (assuming there are no style restrictions involved). Perhaps instead of dealing with `natbib` you would like to try `biblatex` (see [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib))

Also, there are a couple of answers that might help you:

[How to get DOI links in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/how-to-get-doi-links-in-bibliography/64695#64695)

[URL of cited web site in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/url-of-cited-web-site-in-bibliography/36256#36256)

Comment: Are you sure that providing URL-related information would make a bib entry "no longer phcjp compliant"? The bib style file expressly provides for an optional field type called `note`, and I can't see any reason why one couldn't stick URL-related information into that field. Incidentally, I didn't notice the OP saying that she/he was using the `natbib` citation management package, which is something you seem to suggest is the case.

Comment: @Mico Yes, you could add the URL as a note, but since the URL entry exists... why it doesn't appear as default?

Comment: You ask why the `phjcp` bib style doesn't provide a field called `url`. Well, given that the style file appears to have been updated most recently in 1988, my money is on the possibility that the style file's authors simply lacked perfect foresight. :-) At least the authors had the good sense to provide for optional `note` fields...

Comment: @Mico I get your point, and makes complete sense... nevertheless, it is a workaround and not a solution, due to the fact that the URL field exists and should be used for its purpose: harbor URL. What is necessary here is to twitch the .bst file so it displays the URL entry.

Comment: Let's see if the OP weighs in one way or another as to what may constitute an acceptable answer. :-)