# Including DOI field in bibliography while using multibib package

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, multibib, doi

I am new to Latex and I used `multibib package` and .bib file. Every thing works great except there is no `DOI` at the end of entities. All my entities in the bib file have `DOI` filed and `url` and I use `unsrt` and `ieeetr` styles in my bibliography subsections. I check [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/how-to-get-doi-links-in-bibliography) but including `doi package` in Latex with `multibib` results in error `Option clash for package hyperref. \begin{document}` which I don't understand why? I also came up with the idea of editing `biblatex.cfg` by adding `doi=true` line to that file it does not work either (I don't know if i did it in correct way). I use x64 edition of `MiKTeX 2.9` with `BibTex` and `TexStudio 2.6.6`. I want something that results in adding DOI to the end of my bib entities in the PDF with hyperlink like `\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{doi: #1}}` automatically for my doi fields in bib file for `unsrt` and `ieeetr` styles.

As mentioned in comments I provide a minimal sample of the paper at following:

File: Ref.bib

```
@article{a1,
 author             = {Author1},
 title              = {Title1},
 journal            = {Journal1},
 issn               = {xxxx-yyyy},
 year               = {2013},
 volume             = {TR},
 number             = {3},
 pages              = {52-144},
 doi                = {10.10.1038/nphys1170},
 url                = {http://dx.doi.org/10.10.1038/nphys1170}
}

@article{a2,
 author             = {Author2},
 title              = {Title2},
 journal            = {Journal2},
 issn               = {xxxx-yyyy},
 year               = {2012},
 volume             = {k-8},
 number             = {6},
 pages              = {12-17},
 doi                = {10.1002/0470841559.ch1},
 url                = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/0470841559.ch1}
}

@inproceedings{c1, 
 author             = {Author3},
 title              = {Title3},
 booktitle          = {proceedings1},
 year               = {2012},
 pages              = {578-584},
 numpages           = {3},
 doi                = {10.1594/PANGAEA.726855},
 url                = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1594/PANGAEA.726855}
}
```

File: test.tex

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\title{Title Here}
\author{Name Here}

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{Articles,Proceedings}{{Journal Papers},{Conference Papers}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is the minimal abstract ever.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Introduction here.

\section{References}
\nociteArticles{a1,a2}
\bibliographystyleArticles{unsrt}
\bibliographyArticles{Ref}

\nociteProceedings{c1}
\bibliographystyleProceedings{ieeetr}
\bibliographyProceedings{Ref}

\end{document}
```

I hope this could help.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: As long as you use "old" bibliography styles the field `doi` isn't supported. An explanation is given here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/url-of-cited-web-site-in-bibliography -- Because you are starting with, you should switch to `biblatex`, which makes your live easier.

Comment: Thanks for the provided link. I found that I should use `unsrturl` instead of `unsrt`. However I couldn't find any replacement for `ieeetr` to support DOI. By the way, could you provide me equivalent code for the above tex so that I could switch to BibLaTex. I found that I should include `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}` in my tex but I don't know how to use it like `multibib`

Comment: Splitting your bibliography depends on your needs.

Answer (score 8):

As @MarcoDaniel has already pointed out in a comment, the bibliography styles `unsrt` and `ieeetr` are both quite ancient. In fact, neither bib style has been updated materially since about 1986, i.e., *long before* anybody conceived of using digital object identifiers (dois) and URLs in bibliographic references. Unsurprisingly, then, these two styles aren't programmed to recognize fields named `doi` and `url`. If a BibTeX style doesn't know about some fields, the rule is that their contents are ignored.

I suggest you consider using the `unsrtnat` and `IEEEtran` bibliography styles. The former style recognizes both `doi` and `url` fields; the latter recognizes just the `url` field, but not the `doi` field. Depending on your formatting needs, you may want to rename the `doi` field name to `note` and encase the contents of the doi fields in `\url{...}` wrappers -- at least for those entries that will be processed with the `IEEEtran` bib style. For added robustness, I suggest you load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`.