# BibTex: URL:s gets weird whitespace

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, urls

Whenever I cite an online source in my text I encounter strange whitespace. For instance this reference:

```
@ONLINE{factsheet,
author = {Rachel Gill},
title = {Muscular dystrophy: how could stem cells help?},
url = {http://www.eurostemcell.org/factsheet/muscular-dystrophy-how-could-stem-cells-help},
note = {Last updated: 3 Mar 2016, (Used 12/4/2016)},
}
```

results in this pdf:
[image: So much whitespace]

Does anyone know what causes this to happen?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: this isn't a bibtex problem.  the usual url formatting doesn't allow breaks at hyphens, so the entire last part is forced onto a line by itself, and since the block is justified, the only way to make that happen is to stretch the spaces.  it *is* possible to tell the process to allow breaks at hyphens, but for cases where there is only one hyphen in a url, that could easily lead to confusion.  (i'm sure this must be documented in the `url` package manual: `texdoc url`, but i'm not anywhere that i can check it.)

Comment: There is no sensible breakpoint in the url and as your bibliography seems to set \sloppy latex stretch the other spaces. Allow e.g. breaks at hyphen with \usepackage[hyphen]{url}. Or set the bibliography raggedright.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.)

I recommend you load the `URL` package with the options `hyphens`, `spaces`, and `obeyspaces`:

```
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
```

If you load the `hyperref` package as well, be sure to load it after `url`.

Comment: 6k views, a few upvotes, but no answer. Maybe you can add one? [Including DOI field in bibliography while using multibib package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145159)

Comment: @Johannes_B - Thanks. I think there's a leading suspect: The `unsrt` bibliography style was created well before anyone thought of mentioning DOIs in a reference. Unsurprisingly, to me at least, bibliographies typeset with `unsrt ` won't show the contents of `doi` fields. I'll post an answer later today. (Am currently away from a a computer.)