# Overleaf arxiv template does not allow doi links

Tags: hyperref, natbib, templates

I'm using an Overleaf [arXiv/bio-arXiv template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/style-and-template-for-preprints-arxiv-bio-arxiv/fxsnsrzpnvwc) to write my paper. I can't seem to get it to print the doi in the bibliography section. My MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arxiv}
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{doi}

\title{Predict future sale}
\author{Author name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Data mining is a good way to find the relationship between raw data and predict the target we want which is also widely used in different field nowadays. In this project, we implement a lots of technology and method in data mining to predict the sale of an item based on its previous sale. We create a strong model to predict the sales. After evaluating this model, we conclude that this model can be used in normal life for future sale’s prediction. 
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Our project is a competition on Kaggle (Predict Future Sales). We are provided with daily historical sales data (including each products’ sale date, block ,shop price and amount) \cite{kour2014real}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}  
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

and my bibtex file contains

```
@inproceedings{kour2014real,
  title={Real-time segmentation of on-line handwritten arabic script},
  author={Kour, George and Saabne, Raid},
  booktitle={Frontiers in Handwriting Recognition (ICFHR), 2014 14th International Conference on},
  pages={417--422},
  year={2014},
  organization={IEEE},
  doi="10.1109/ICFHR.2014.76"
}
```

There are no package incompatibilities or error messages so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The bibliography style is old and doesn't know modern fields like doi.

Comment: Additionally I would have assumed that `unsrt` is not compatible with `natbib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to depend highly on your `bibliographystyle`, see e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309869/237192). You maybe want to change to a newer style, e.g. `unsrtnat`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@inproceedings{kour2014real,
  title={Real-time segmentation of on-line handwritten arabic script},
  author={Kour, George and Saabne, Raid},
  booktitle={Frontiers in Handwriting Recognition (ICFHR), 2014 14th International Conference on},
  pages={417--422},
  year={2014},
  organization={IEEE},
  doi={10.1109/ICFHR.2014.76}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{arxiv}
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{doi}

\title{Predict future sale}
\author{Author name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Data mining is a good way to find the relationship between raw data and predict the target we want which is also widely used in different field nowadays. In this project, we implement a lots of technology and method in data mining to predict the sale of an item based on its previous sale. We create a strong model to predict the sales. After evaluating this model, we conclude that this model can be used in normal life for future sale’s prediction. 
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Our project is a competition on Kaggle (Predict Future Sales). We are provided with daily historical sales data (including each products’ sale date, block, shop price and amount) \cite{kour2014real}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}  
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

---

### Edit

After reading your comment, let me propose using `biblatex` together with `numeric` style:
[image: Result using biblatex]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@inproceedings{kour2014real,
  title={Real-time segmentation of on-line handwritten arabic script},
  author={Kour, George and Saabne, Raid},
  booktitle={Frontiers in Handwriting Recognition (ICFHR), 2014 14th International Conference on},
  pages={417--422},
  year={2014},
  organization={IEEE},
  doi={10.1109/ICFHR.2014.76}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,doi=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Our project is a competition on Kaggle (Predict Future Sales). We are provided with daily historical sales data (including each products’ sale date, block, shop price and amount) \cite{kour2014real}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't mind using `natbib` or `biblatex`, I just want something that outputs something similar to `unsrt` (numbered refs in the order that they appear in the text) plus a doi.

Comment: @MedullaOblongata Please see the edit. `biblatex` can be further customized if you need it.