# How can I add the DOI to a Vancouver style bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, doi

I need to submit an article to a journal with *Vancouver* style referencing. *Vancouver* style can be used simply by including `\bibliographystyle{vancouver}`. The `.bst` is defined as here: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/vancouver

The journal also requires a DOI after the reference. I have included these into my `.bib`. For example:

```
@ARTICLE{Berglund2001,
  author = {Berglund, Anders and Gunilla Rosenqvist},
  title = {Male pipefish prefer ornamented females},
  journal = {Animal Behaviour},
  year = {2001},
  pages = {345-350},
  doi = {10.1006/anbe.2000.1599}
}
```

However, this DOI is not automatically printed in my bibliography. A related question is posted here: [URL of cited web site in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/url-of-cited-web-site-in-bibliography). The DOI is defined in *Vancouver*, as can be seen when opening the `.bst`. Therefore, I think there should be an easy way to make it print the DOI as well, without the need to change the `bibliographystyle`.

How can I add DOI to the bibliography when using *Vancouver* style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is provided here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/vancouver/FAQ.

> The doi formatting is disabled by default. You can enable it by changing the following line in vancouver.bst from:

```
#0 'adddoiresolver := % 0=no DOI resolver; 1=include it
```

> to:

```
#1 'adddoiresolver := % 0=no DOI resolver; 1=include it
```

Comment: I figured out the answer while writing up this question. It was silly of me not to figure it out earlier. Anyway, I decided to continue posting the question, as well as the answer, on here.

Comment: If anyone can help me figure out how to change the DOI part into a DOI-URL hyperlink, that would be appreciated. The answer is probably contained within .bst, but I'm not familiar enough with this type of code to do it myself.

Comment: Ok, this is done by changing the #0 in "#0 'hrefform := % 0=no crossrefs; 1=hypertex xrefs; 2=hyperref refs" to #2.