# Display content of @misc{ ... url = {...} in Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, chicago-style

I have the following `.bib` file

```
@misc{TestEntry.2020,
 author = {Last Name, First Name},
 year = {2020},
 title = {Title of Homepage},
 url = {https://tex.stackexchange.com},
 urldate = {01.01.2020}
}
```

and the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{natbib}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Introduction}
    \paragraph{Paragraph title}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
        diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
        aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
        duo dolores et ea rebum \citealt{TestEntry.2020}.

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{Literature}
\end{document}
```

The result contains a bibliography like this [image: Bibliography status quo]

However, I would like the content of the fields `url` and `urldate` to be included in the bibliography, e.g. in the form `Available online at: https://tex.stackexchange.com, last accessed on 01.01.2020`.

Can anyone point me to how I can achieve this?

Comment: From the following web link, you can find the solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/url-of-cited-web-site-in-bibliography

Answer (score 2):

You wrote,

> I would like the content of the fields `url` and `urldate` to be included in the bibliography, e.g. in the form
>
> ```
> Available online at: https://tex.stackexchange.com, last accessed on 01.01.2020.
> ```

The `chicago` bibliography style is actually quite old. For sure, it does not truly represent the bibliographic formatting guidelines of the current, *viz.*, 17th, edition of the *Chicago Manual of Style*. If you need to adhere to "Chicago"'s *current* guidelines, you should look into using `biblatex` and its `biblatex-chicago` style.

If you decide to stay with BibTeX and the by now rather obsolete `chicago` bibliography style, you should also be aware of the fact that it is *so old* that "Chicago" made no mention of how to format `url` and `urldate` fields back then. If a bibliography style doesn't specify what should be done with certain fields, these fields will simply be ignored by BibTeX. That's precisely what you're experiencing.

Fortunately for you, though, the `chicago` bib style does specify what to do with the `note` field, for virtually all entry types, including the `@misc` entry type. Hence, you may want to rewrite the bib entry in question as

```
@misc{TestEntry.2020,
 author = {Last Name, First Name},
 year   = {2020},
 title  = {Title of Homepage},
 note   = {Available online at: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}, 
           last accessed on 01.01.2020}
}
```

Since this approach involves using a macro called `\url`, you will also need to load a package that defines a macro by that name. I suggest you load the `xurl` package, as it permits abritrary line break points in URL strings.

A full MWE (mininum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{Literature.bib}
@misc{TestEntry.2020,
 author = {Last Name, First Name},
 year   = {2020},
 title  = {Title of Homepage},
 note   = {Available online at: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}, 
           last accessed on 01.01.2020}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\usepackage{xurl} % for "\url" macro
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citealt{TestEntry.2020}.
\bibliography{Literature}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up request raised in a comment. To process the bibliography and citation call-outs using the `biblatex` package -- more precisely: the `biblatex-chicago` package -- I suggest you make some modifications to the entry at hand:

- The good news is that `biblatex` does know about fields called `url` and `urldate`. However, it's necessary to cast the contents of the `urldate` field in `yyyy-mm--dd` format (aka ISO8601 format): `2020-01-01` is good, but `01.01.2020` is not.
- I would change the entry type from BibTeX's catch-all `@misc` to `@online`.
- Unless you have a very good reason for using BibTeX rather than `biber` as the back-end program need to sort the bibliographic entries, do run `biber`, not BibTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{Literature.bib}
@online{TestEntry.2020,
 author = {Last Name, First Name},
 year   = {2020},
 title  = {Title of Homepage},
 url    = {https://tex.stackexchange.com},
 urldate= {2020-01-01}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{Literature.bib}

\usepackage{xurl} % for "\url" macro
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citeauthor{TestEntry.2020}, \citeyear{TestEntry.2020}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's awesome, thank you! Would you be able to elaborate on the equivalent code using `biblatex-chicago`?

Comment: @Ivo - Please see the addendum I posted just now.